# Rolling AIS Stream at regular time intervals

Tags: linux, gpsd

I'm receiving an AIS data stream in a Linux server using `gpsdecode`:

```
nc -ul -p portNumber | gpsdecode -j | tee decodeTest.txt
```

This process is always running and what I want to do is to have a new `decodeTest.txt` every 24h, each one with a proper name based on the date+time for example.

Any clues of how to face the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally reach to this solution using `ncat`, but I think is portable to `nc`:

```
while true do
ncat -lu -p 56045 --recv-only -i 60s | ...
end
```

With this if a disconnection occurs or data sender stops, `ncat` will start a new connection and everything will continue.